# Where/how do the TCL variables saved?

Tags: tcl

I am looking at the TCL source code and trying to understand the mechanism how the TCL variables are managed internally. For example, given the following TCL script:

```
set a 1
set b 2
```

I looked at Tcl_SetObjCmd() function, it sets an object to interpreter and that is it. So when the first line runs, there is a Tcl_Obj is set to interpreter with value "1", but I do not find where this object is retrieved which leads to my ultimate goal, where does that object get stored?

Any pointer is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more complicated than it appears. The simple version is that the Tcl expression there would call [Tcl_SetVar2Ex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclLib/SetVar.htm) as something like `Tcl_SetVar2Ex(interp, "a", NULL, Tcl_NewIntObj(1), 0)` to setup a variable called 'a' in the interpreter with the value given. It will also assign this to to the interpreter's result using [Tcl_SetObjResult](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclLib/SetResult.htm).

However, modern Tcl does byte compilation and executes something else. We can examine this as shown below:

```
% tcl::unsupported::disassemble script {set a 1}
ByteCode 0x0x10e0110, refCt 1, epoch 3, interp 0x0xde9d00 (epoch 3)
  Source "set a 1"
  Cmds 1, src 7, inst 6, litObjs 2, aux 0, stkDepth 2, code/src 0.00
  Commands 1:
      1: pc 0-4, src 0-6
  Command 1: "set a 1"
    (0) push1 0     # "a"
    (2) push1 1     # "1"
    (4) storeScalarStk 
    (5) done
```

So the byte compiled version actually pushes the name and the value onto the stack then calls this storeScalarStk function. Some digging in the sources shows this gets executed in generic/tclExecute.c as `INST_STORE_SCALAR_STK` which basically just jumps to `doCallPtrSetVar` where it calls `TclPtrSetVar` which does a similar job to the Tcl_SetVar2Ex function from the public API. The main advantage of the byte compilation is on repeat runs where the syntactic parsing has already been handled so subsequent execution of a function is much faster than the first run.

Your basic question seems to be about how the value was returned to the interpreter. The interp structure has a result slot that is manipulated with `Tcl_SetObjResult` and `Tcl_GetObjResult`. Functions that want to return a result to script level assign a Tcl_Obj to the interp result.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. The problem I am dealing is, when TCL cannot allocate memory(the ckalloc fails), TCL just panics. I like to use setjmp/longjmp to exit as clean as possible, this requires de-allocating the variables already allocated. I will trace tclExecute.c for clue. But advice is appreciated!

Comment: @my_question If ckalloc failed for a small allocation, you're totally stuck: there's no memory left. Don't worry too much about cleaning up, as you're so far out of resources that recovery is really extremely unlikely. Is this happening in live code shipped to customers, or just in testing?